# SSIS Data flow task - trying to execute a stored procedure as part of the OL DB SQL command

Tags: ssis

Question:  Can a stored procedure be ran as part of the SQLCommand in the OLE DB provider?

I'm new to SSIS and have gotten simple SQL commands to work.  But I'm trying to use a stored procedure inside the SQL command.  Results of the Main SQL are pulled from the pivot table created by the stored procedure (which is used as a temporary table)

The stored procedure is one of the JOINS in the main SQL (actually it's an 'OUTER APPLY xxx (where xxx is the stored procedure name) as Alias'.  The purpose of the stored procedure is to create a single row of results where normally there would have been one row per account listing all DX.

```
         ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Sample source table
   account   line   DX
   acct1      1     abc123
   acct1      2     cdf123
   acct1      3     xxx12
   acct2      1     bcv12
   acct2      2     xul35

Note:  the Account is passed to the Stored procedure from the main table

```
         ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Sample result generated by the stored procedure:
   account   ICD01    ICD02    ICD03
   acct1     abc123   cdf123   xxx12
   acct2     bcv12    xul35

note:  the stored procedure takes and create a column (created by ColName + Line#)  ie ColName = DX + Line 1 = DX1 (which is the row header).  Vs having 3 rows returned for Acct1 & 2 rows returned for Acct2

```
         ---------------------------------------------------------
```

sample sql
select table1.account_id  'Account'
,ICD.[ICD01]    'ICD01' 
,ICD.[ICD50]    'IC02'

from Table1
  left outer join Table2  on table2 = tablel
  join table3 on table1= table3

OUTER APPLY StoredProcedure(table1.ACCOUNT_ID) as [ICD]

where table1.date_time between @Date_From and @Date_To

```
         ---------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run the SSIS package, the Headers are created in the file & the correct number of rows are returned, but no Data is pulled for the columns created by the stored procedure.  Running from the Data Flow.  I did see posts on adding an 'Execute SQL Task' in the Control Flow, but my problem is the Account_ID is passed to the stored procedure (to pull only data for those Accounts) from Table1 so I can't run the Stored procedure outside of the Data Flow before the Data Flow SQL is ran (from what I can tell - but as I said, I'm new to SSIS).

When I run the SQL via SQL Server Management Studio, I get what I'm expecting.  So I know the Stored procedure works.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Start a profiler trace and then run your package and see if and how the SQL Command sent from SSIS differs from the one you enter into SSMS that works as expected.   (When you say it works in SSMS, I assume you mean the exact same query you've entered into your SSIS OLEDB command, and not JUST the stored procedure or some other smaller part of it.)  2. Take the command that SSIS generates in the profiler trace, and try executing it in SSMS and see what happens.   Maybe the problem is the way your parameters are mapped, and not the stored prc at all.

Comment: OLEDB queries use ? to enter parameters. So try exec [sp_name] ? ? ? and then go to the parameter table and map values from variables.

Comment: Yes, the exact same Query that executes correctly in SSMS.  Not to sound dumb, but by add the parameters, do you mean, add the 'account_id' that's passed from the Main SQL to the stored procedure or all of the values (columns) that can be returned by the stored procedure?

Comment: forgot to ask:  One more thing, are you saying type 'exec [sp] ???'.  If so, can I do that in the 'from' section (joins.... where I use the outer apply) to join the data created by the stored procedure?

Comment: OK - you're not going to believe this.  But I was having trouble starting the profiler trace, so I decided to delete the destination & recreate it (because when I went into the source & clicked on 'preview', I could see the expected output).  And after running the package, it's now working...... Sorry to have troubled you, I should have tried this.  So no changes to the original SQL were needed.  Thanks for your suggestions.  We can consider this question Answered.